# Pseudocode for Binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree

In a binary search tree, the predecessor of a key x is a key y that is smaller than 
x, and for which there is no other key z such that z is smaller than x and greater 
than y.

Give the pseudocode for an algorithm that takes a key x and returns the 
predecessor y or nil if x is the smallest key in the tree. Assume that the binary 
search tree is represented using arrays left, right, and parent. Give the pseudocode 
for any subsidiary functions that are used.

I'm not really sure how to approach this question. But heres my attempt:

Pseudocode:

```
//Takes in key x

BST(x)
{

if ( x < parent[x] )

    return nil

if( parent[x] < x )

   return parent[x] // parent[x] = y
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was from a poor readover of your question - what you are looking for is just the predecessor in the tree.
http://www.quora.com/How-can-you-find-successors-and-predecessors-in-a-binary-search-tree-in-order

here is the code they use in that post:

```
public static TreeNode findPredecessor(TreeNode node)
{
    if (node == null)
        return null;

    if (node.getLeft() != null)
        return findMaximum(node.getLeft());

    TreeNode parent = node.getParent();

    TreeNode y = parent;
    TreeNode x = node;
    while (y != null && x == y.getLeft())
    {
        x = y;
        y = y.getParent();
    }

    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no any left node present then there cant be any predecessor. Otherwise max element in left subtree will be the predecessor

```
public int findmax(Node root) {
     if (root == NULL) 
      return INT_MIN; 

    int res = root->data; 
    int lres = findMax(root->left); 
    int rres = findMax(root->right); 
    if (lres > res) 
      res = lres; 
    if (rres > res) 
      res = rres; 
    return res; 
}

public int findPredecessor(Node node) {

     if(node == null) return null;
     if(node->left == null) return null;
     return findMax(node->left);
}
```